# Azure Document DB – JS file with server-side API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I’m using Cosmos DB with SQL API. I keep definitions of stored procedures in my project in JS files and initialize them during startup if it’s needed. I’m using WebStorm as JS code editor and it have really helpful feature: autocomplete. But to use is I need JS library file. Is it possible to download JS file used to generate this documentation:

https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cosmos DB JS server code is part of the page you linked.

You can find the page containing the `DocDbWrapperScript.js` [here](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/DocDbWrapperScript.js.html)

If you just want the raw JS file then you can get that [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Elfocrash/1d10ef824d56d3f63f9a65ea26dae9ee/raw/032bed0d1c18224c28eff46862b52d1bb97115e3/DocDbWrapperScript.js)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.